# How to Display the Text using .TextContent?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the message Hey friends by overwriting the HTML with .TextContent in the JS. So instead of just saying Hey! I want it to say Hey Friends!

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>


<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>friends</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- This links to the js code specific for this page -->
    <script src="multiwrites.js"></script>

    <script src="multiwrites2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title">Hey!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var message;
message = 'Hey Friends';

var elName = document.getElementById('title');
elName.textContent = message;
```

Comment: It works just make sure your `<script>` tags are just before `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your script tags after the DOM nodes they will access:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Friends</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="title">hello</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById('title');
    el.textContent = "hello world";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or waiting for the DOM to be "ready", I can see you have included jQuery so that could be done with:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // In here the whole DOM will be "ready"
  // Using jQuery API instead of native DOM API.
  $('#title').text('hello world');
});
```